# Correct way of logging request and responses witch wcfCore

Tags: .net-core

How to properly configure request and response logging for wcfCore?

On old wcf it was:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any options to configure such logging. Therefore, I implemented the desired functionality using interfaces:

IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior.

https://github.com/lsmolinski/CoreWCFServiceWithRequestAndResponseLoging